# distinct in sql

Tags: sql, select, distinct, rows

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CASE WHEN state=18 THEN lga ELSE 'Others' END) LGA,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN choice=21 THEN choice END ) NDCH
FROM bio   
GROUP BY lga
```

My expectation is for it to give me all LGA with state=18, and if the state is not equal to 18 let them be grouped as 'Others', but I usually have more than one 'Others'.
Please help.

Comment: When you say "usually", you mean in your output, right?

Comment: What is the `COUNT()` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a `group by` on the case statement:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN state=18 THEN lga ELSE 'Others' END LGA
,       COUNT(CASE WHEN choice=21 THEN choice END) NDCH
FROM    bio
GROUP BY
        CASE WHEN state=18 THEN lga ELSE 'Others' END
```